# Using MapServer, MapCache and WMS?

Tags: wms, mapserver, mapcache

I just installed mapserver and mapcache on a Debian server. I struggled to put those two to work. Now when I call this url (by the way I don't know if it's the good one) //myserver/cgi-bin/mapserv/service/wms?map=/opt/basemaps/osm-google.map&mode=browse&template=openlayers, I get the map but it is just a single image ! no tiles. If the map appears this means my mapcache works fine ?
Is there anything i missed.

```
./mapserv -v
MapServer version 6.5-dev OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE
```

Comment: To help us help you, you should provide a simple mapfile and your mapcache configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You have installed two separate programs:
- MapServer that is a map engine
- MapCache that is a tile cache for rendered images
With your request you hit Mapserver (by using a peculiar Mapserver specific "browse" mode). The MapCache service will be found from another URL `http://server/mapcache/?` as you can see by reading the documentation http://mapserver.org/mapcache/index.html
You will need to read the documentation in any case because you must configure Mapcache to read maps from the Mapserver side before you can make the whole factory to run.